# Excel: how to do COUNTIF with OR function or Startwith

Tags: excel, countif

I have a text column that has different texts, also another column which indicates "t" or "f" Based on the column in the text and "t" or "f" value I ant to do a count.

```
=AND(G2="t",F2="Hello"orF2="HelloWorld")
```

I tried about but it gave me error, How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
=AND(G2="t", OR(F2="Hello", F2="HelloWorld"))
```

You can probably just copy this formula down the column you need to count and then below that do

```
=COUNTIF(your range of AND formulas, "=TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a couple of countifs functions

```
=countifs(G:G,"t",F:F,"Hello")+countifs(G:G,"t",F:F,"HelloWorld")
```

this does your count without the helper column.  The two functions are needed due to the OR in your formula